# Data migration from one table to another

Tags: database, plsql

I want to do data migration from one table to another table. Source table has country names in free floating text and destination table need to have country code.

For example source table has country names with incorrect spelling.

e.g. United Stts of Americ --> USA
Franc --> FRA

Can we have some key value pair in SQL where we can store these incorrect country names to 3 character country code?

Comment: Are you using Oracle? Which version? How many different values in the source table?

Comment: Also, you describe this as a "data migration". Is this a one-off exercise or an ongoing process? Are you looking for an automated solution or something which requires "skill and judgement" to get the translations right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PL/SQL tag reads as "Oracle". If that's so, see if something like this helps.

Sample tables:

```
SQL> select * from state;

ABB NAME
--- ------------------------
FRA France
USA United States of America
GER Germany

SQL> select * from garbage;

NAME
----------------------
United Stts of Americ
Unted states of Amerca
Frnce
France
Gremany

SQL>
```

Query:

```
SQL> select g.name, s.name, s.abbr
  2  from state s join garbage g
  3  on utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(g.name, s.name) > 90;

NAME                   NAME                     ABB
---------------------- ------------------------ ---
Frnce                  France                   FRA
France                 France                   FRA
United Stts of Americ  United States of America USA
Unted states of Amerca United States of America USA
Gremany                Germany                  GER

SQL>
```

Tweak *similarity* value, if necessary. I used `90`, see how it behaves for your data.

Comment: Remember that Oracle's Jaro-Winkler implementation is case sensitive, so `France` and `FRANCE` does not score 100. Also, we get false positives on quite high thresholds. For instance, `Iraq` scores 88 against `Iran` (and vice versa, obvs). `Ira` scores 94 against both `Iran` and `Iraq`. So I think similarity matching is a good starting point but I wouldn't necessarily rely on it as a complete solution. Of course, it rather depends on what the Seeker wants to do with the data.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, @APC, I agree with everything you said.